# Bad quality in Cheese Webcam Booth Software

Tags: webcam, cheese

I installed Cheese Webcam Booth from Software Center to 11.10, Cheese worked beautiful in 11.04 but in .10 the image is so bad (I've put a picture of it), I like the functionalities of it and dont want to use any other webcam softwares, is there a way to fix it? [image: Here]

Comment: even though you do not want to use another software - can you try another software to see if the problem occurs there as well? This helps to find out where the problem is.

Comment: i tried camorama, and it worked for me, with good quality, i dont see other webcam softwares around with much functionality, can u suggest one pls?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you give a try on other webcam softwares? **guvcview** and **camorama** are good alternatives. I prefer "guvcview", lightweight and highly configurable. The only thing "guvcview" misses is automaticaly take pictures every "x" seconds (which is there in Cheese).

Comment: here in 2021 `guvcview` is way worse than `cheese`

Comment: `cheese` comes by default so i guess cheese must be the best option so far. Hoping future updates of `cheese` will work on improving quality.